# issue with JSDoc and readme file

Tags: jsdoc

I am trying to use a README.md file with JSDoc when launching jsdoc I get the following error.

*ERROR: Unable to parse /Users/patrick/workflow/README.md: Topic reference is used, but the pipelineOperator plugin was not passed a "proposal": "hack" or "smart" option. (1:0)*

My README file does seem correct.

Any idea on how to solve the issue ?

````
# Foobar

Foobar is a Python library for dealing with word pluralization.

## Installation

Use the package manager [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) to install foobar.

```bash
pip install foobar
```

## Usage

```python
import foobar

# returns 'words'
foobar.pluralize('word')

# returns 'geese'
foobar.pluralize('goose')

# returns 'phenomenon'
foobar.singularize('phenomena')
```

## Contributing
Pull requests are welcome. For major changes, please open an issue first to discuss what you would like to change.

Please make sure to update tests as appropriate.

## License
[MIT](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/)
````

Comment: How are you invoking `jsdoc`? What plugins and template are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the modules directory and reinstalled it. All good, now.